# How Can I Access an Array stored in a JS file from Another JS File?

Tags: javascript, arrays, module, require, visual-web-developer

I'm practicing how to web develop in general and seem to encounter a problem when trying to access an array contained in the file race.js from a file named app.js.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnGjL.png)

and I'm trying to print out this list of fantasy races in app.js through this function:

```js
function generateTraits(){
    let content = document.getElementById('listOfTraits');

    let list = "<ul>";
        
    for(let i = 0; i <RACE.RACE.length;i++) {
        list += "<li>" + RACE.RACE[i] + "</li>";
    }

    list += "</ul>";

    content.innerHTML = list;
}

generateTraits();
```

When I refresh my page, the list is not generated so i can only conclude that i wasn't able to export it properly despite searching for an answer everywhere online.
Would anybody know how to do so please?

Comment: What's RACE supposed to be?

Comment: An array containing strings of fantasy races

Comment: and where are you getting this from? Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

If you link two js file in your index html, this should work. If not try using

```
export { RACE }
```

in your js file where RACE array located
in your js file where you want to loop

```
import { RACE } from 'your first js file path'
```

Hope this help

Comment: hey! what do u mean by linking the two js files in the index html plz?

Comment: also, i did try your second solution and it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: link two js file means
<script scr="first.js"></script>
<script scr="second.js"></script>
in your index html...if second solution didn't work, try warping every js code in a class and export that class and import it on another js file